# Can I make this assignment expression more compact in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

I am trying to initialise connectivity manager using applicationContext. 
I expect user to send activity context and then i will fetch applicationContext from it. However, I can not really be sure that the user will not send applicationContext directly. I have written an if else statement to initialise connectivityManager but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. Anything with `let` or `elvis` operator maybe?

```
/**
 * if user has passed application Context, we use it to get system service,
 * else we get applicationContext from it and use that instead.
 */
private val connectivityManager = if (context.applicationContext == null)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
else
    context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
```

Comment: how can applicationContext be null?

Comment: As says @ViktorYakunin applicationContext can probably never be null

Comment: @ViktorYakunin, applicationContext.applicationContext can be null right? If context in the code snippet above is actually applicationContext, then applicationContext.applicationContext would be null maybe?

Comment: not right, it will be non-null even if you perform applicationContext.applicationContext.applicationContext.applicationContext

Comment: Great, I din't know that. So we can just call context.applicationContext blindly on the context argument and it will give us the applicationContext. Amazing.

Comment: Btw, return type of getApplicationContext() is a Nullable. I don't understand this bit.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just `Context!`, so there is no nullability annotation on it?

Comment: yes, It is Context! and not @Nullable annotation. But Context! means it can be null right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private val connectivityManager = 
    context.run { applicationContext ?: this }.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
```

But I think you can move that to an extension function

```
private val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager = 
    context.findSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)

inline fun <reified T> Context.findSystemService(val serviceTag: String): T = 
    (applicationContext ?: this).getSystemService(serviceTag) as T
```

Comment: Or just `(applicationContext ?: this).getSystemService(serviceTag) as T
 ` will prevent a new lambda instance

Comment: shouldn't make a new lambda because it's inline, no? But you are correct

Comment: no, inline will replace with the complete body. I mean for the `run { }` call the parameter is a new instance, this could be prevented using the parentheses expression

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, I think this is the solution that I was looking for but the extension function is a little difficult for me to understand. So you created a new function that will call getSystemService on applicationContext and it uses run function to find applicationContext. But I still don't understand how it is going to Type cast the returned value to ConnectivityManager. How would the function know T stands for ConnectivityManager? Is is because of that reified keyword?

Comment: And that I specified the type for the variable beforehand instead of casting at the end

Comment: Since you're assigning the result of the `findSystemService` call to a property of type `ConnectivityManager`, the required return type can be inferred. You could also state it explicitly as `context.findSystemService<ConnectivityManager>(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)`.